# Create a "floating" control in C# (WinForm app) without WPF

Tags: c#, winforms, layout, controls

I want to create a "floating" control - like Visual Studio's ones (The solution explorer, for example).

How can I implement such thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is anything built-in to WinForms but there are several third-party controls that allow this functionality.

One popular set of controls is the ones from Telerik: http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/dock.aspx

And another one is the controls from Ingragistics: http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/windockmanager.aspx#Overview

Both these are commercial packages and I don't know of any free packages that offer the same.

Comment: Here's one open source under MIT license - http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using LollipopUIControls.UIManagers;

namespace Gamasis.Apps.Controls
{
public class FloatingButton : Button
{
public FloatingButton()
{
    SetStyle((ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor | ControlStyles.UserPaint), true);
    DoubleBuffered = true;

    Size = new Size(50, 50);
    BackColor = Color.Transparent;

    SF.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    SF.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    AnimationTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(AnimationTick);
}

#region  Variables

Timer AnimationTimer = new Timer { Interval = 1 };

FontManager font = new FontManager();
StringFormat SF = new StringFormat();
Rectangle StringRectangle;

bool Focus = false;
int margintop = 0, marginleft = 0, marginright = 0, marginBottom = 0;
int xx;
int yy;

float SizeAnimation = 0;
float SizeIncNum;

string fontcolor = "#FAFAFA";
string Backcolor = "#039BE5";

Color EnabledBGColor;
Color EnabledBorderColor;
Color StringColor;

Color DisabledBGColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#B0BEC5");
Color DisabledStringColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FAFAFA");
Color NonColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e3e5e7");

Image bGImage = null;


#endregion

#region  Properties
[Category("Custom")]
public string BGColor
{
    get { return Backcolor; }
    set
    {
        Backcolor = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
[Category("Custom")]
public string FontColor
{
    get { return fontcolor; }
    set
    {
        fontcolor = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}

[Browsable(false)]
public Font Font
{
    get { return base.Font; }
    set { base.Font = value; }
}

[Browsable(false)]
public Color ForeColor
{
    get { return base.ForeColor; }
    set { base.ForeColor = value; }
}

[Category("Custom")]
public Image BGImage
{
    get { return bGImage; }
    set { bGImage = value; }
}

ImageSizeLevel bGimgSize = ImageSizeLevel.peque2;

public ImageSizeLevel BGimgSize
{
    get { return bGimgSize; }
    set { bGimgSize = value; }
}
#endregion

#region Events
protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);

    EnabledBGColor = Color.FromArgb(30, ColorTranslator.FromHtml(BGColor));//StringColor);
    EnabledBorderColor = Color.FromArgb(20, ColorTranslator.FromHtml(BGColor));//StringColor);
    Refresh();
}
protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);

    EnabledBGColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(BGColor);
    EnabledBorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(BGColor);
    Refresh();
}
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);

    EnabledBGColor = Color.FromArgb(30, StringColor);
    Refresh();

    xx = e.X;
    yy = e.Y;

    Focus = true;
    AnimationTimer.Start();
    Invalidate();
}
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseUp(e);
    Focus = false;
    AnimationTimer.Start();
    Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnTextChanged(System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    Invalidate();
}
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    //StringRectangle = new Rectangle(3, 0, Width - 6, Height - 6);
}
#endregion

protected override void OnResize(System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    //SizeIncNum = Width / 34;
    SizeIncNum = Width / 10;

}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    var G = e.Graphics;


    #region Default rectangle
    //G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality | SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    //G.Clear(Parent.BackColor);

    //StringColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(fontcolor);

    //var BG = DrawHelper.CreateRoundRect(1, 1, Width - 3, Height - 3, 1);
    //Region region = new Region(BG);

    //G.FillPath(new SolidBrush(Enabled ? EnabledBGColor : Color.White), BG);
    //G.DrawPath(new Pen(Enabled ? EnabledBorderColor : Color.White), BG);

    //G.SetClip(region, CombineMode.Replace);

    ////The Ripple Effect
    //G.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, StringColor)), xx - (SizeAnimation / 2), yy - (SizeAnimation / 2), SizeAnimation, SizeAnimation);

    //G.DrawString(Text, font.Roboto_Medium10, new SolidBrush(Enabled ? StringColor : DisabledStringColor), R, SF);

    #endregion

    #region Circle

    //G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    //G.Clear(BackColor);

    //GraphicsPath bgbtn = new GraphicsPath();
    //bgbtn.AddEllipse(0, 0, Width - 5, Height - 5);

    //GraphicsPath bgShadow = new GraphicsPath();
    //bgShadow.AddEllipse(0, 0, Width - 2, Height - 2);

    //G.FillPath(new SolidBrush(NonColor), bgShadow);
    //G.DrawPath(new Pen(NonColor), bgShadow);

    //G.FillPath(new SolidBrush(Color.DeepSkyBlue), bgbtn);            
    //G.DrawPath(new Pen(Color.DeepSkyBlue), bgbtn);

    #endregion


    ///----------------------------
    G.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    G.Clear(Parent.BackColor);

    StringColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(fontcolor);

    //var BG = DrawHelper.CreateRoundRect(1, 1, Width - 3, Height - 3, 1);
    //Círculo principal
    GraphicsPath bgbtn = new GraphicsPath();
    bgbtn.AddEllipse(2, 0, Width - 6, Height - 6);

    //Círculo para la sombra
    GraphicsPath bgShadow = new GraphicsPath();
    bgShadow.AddEllipse(2, 4, Width - 6, Height - 6);

    // se dibuja la sombra
    G.FillPath(new SolidBrush(NonColor), bgShadow);
    G.DrawPath(new Pen(NonColor), bgShadow);

    //sedibuja el círculo principal sobre la sombra
    G.FillPath(new SolidBrush(Enabled ? ColorTranslator.FromHtml(BGColor) : DisabledBGColor), bgbtn);
    G.DrawPath(new Pen(Enabled ? ColorTranslator.FromHtml(BGColor) : DisabledBGColor), bgbtn);

    // Se da a la región forma de círculo/elipse
    Region region = new Region(bgbtn);//BG);
    G.SetClip(region, CombineMode.Replace);

    //The Ripple Effect
    if (Enabled)
        G.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, EnabledBGColor)), xx - (SizeAnimation / 2), yy - (SizeAnimation / 2), SizeAnimation, SizeAnimation);
    StringRectangle = new Rectangle((int)bgbtn.GetBounds().Location.X, (int)bgbtn.GetBounds().Location.Y,
        (int)bgbtn.GetBounds().Size.Width, (int)bgbtn.GetBounds().Size.Height);
    G.DrawString(Text, font.Roboto_Medium15, new SolidBrush(Enabled ? StringColor : DisabledStringColor), StringRectangle, SF);
    if (bGImage != null)
    {
        float imgX = 0, imgY = 0;
        imgY = (bgbtn.GetBounds().Size.Height - (int)bGimgSize) / 2;
        imgX = ((bgbtn.GetBounds().Size.Width - (int)bGimgSize) + 2) / 2;
        G.DrawImage(bGImage, imgX, imgY, (float)bGimgSize, (float)bGimgSize);
    }
}

protected void AnimationTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Focus)
    {
        if (SizeAnimation < Width + 250)
        {
            SizeAnimation += SizeIncNum;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (SizeAnimation > 0)
        {
            SizeAnimation = 0;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}

public enum ImageSizeLevel
{
    peque = 12, peque1 = 24, peque2 = 32,
    maso = 48, maso1 = 56, maso2 = 64,
    grande = 72, grande1 = 86, grande2 = 96,
    monstruo = 128, monstruo1 = 256, monstruo2 = 512
}
}
}
```